# Mail through Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

How can we **send mail** using JavaScript?

Comment: You can't do that with pure JS.

Comment: in anycase you need SMTP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible directly. You'll have to use a server side language, such as ASP.Net, and call a server side email method using [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). Here's a quick example using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "MyController/SendMail",
    data: { recipient = "bob@someplace.com" },
    success: function(data, status) {
       alert("Mail sent");
    },
    error: function() {
       alert("Mail failed.");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, from client-interfacing JS, to send an XMLHttpRequest request to a URI that understands how to send mail that corresponds to a given payload -- you will need to listen for those asynchronous HTTP request server side using some kind of server side language, though!

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible, you need some [server-side programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting) such as PHP, ASP, Python, etc.

Comment: i am using php . so pls guide with reference to php

Answer (score 0):

Like said before, it's not possible with Javascript alone. Even the HTML5  Websocket API won't help.

However, it's not necessary to implement a server bridge. There's a common workaround using a Flash/SWF as bridge, which can open real socket connections. In theory this allows full client-side smtp connections. Though, I'm sure nobody has yet done that, nor would it seem feasible for you.