# Web sites contact forms

Tags: javascript, html

I see many sites with "Contact forms", with textboxes for name, surname, email, and a message.
How are this information sent to the company? Is an email sent, or this information is stored in a database?
If an email is sent, could anyone tell me how to send emails with javascript without opening the email client on the user's pc?

Thanks a lot

Comment: javascript by itself can sent an email. you need to use server side technologies to do that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mail through Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690094/mail-through-javascript)

Comment: It's not that hard. http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_mail

Comment: `mailto:` links like this don't work on Chrome, though. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/7l8_exIDFY8

Comment: @NobleMushtak That is *not* how standard 'contact forms' work; your example requires the user to have a local email client. OP is referring to a web app that sends the information from the web server itself.

Comment: Well it's not very logic that my question is downvoted while the replies are upvoted. Are people who answer stupid questions smart?

Comment: @admdrew Oh...So a Python script in a server using the `email` package or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

your only option is using a mailto in an href. This relies on the user sending the email themselves. You might be able to do something with javascript to populated the email .e.g

```
"mailto:"+emailTo+"&subject="+subjectText+"&body="+bodyText
```

try to see this [Need to Send Email from HTML pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818962/need-to-send-email-from-html-pages)

Answer (score 1):

Generally these forms will POST the information to a server at a particular url.  The maintainer will set up their server so that this url runs a script.  That script may send an email and/or add the information to a database.

You could set up the server yourself, or use someone else's server that will do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution: [Google Contact Forms](https://drive.google.com/templates?q=contact+form&sort=user&view=public#)